# way to get exact below format of current date

Tags: c#

Is there any way to get exact below format of current date- 18 Aug 2010.
I tried -

```
 string dt = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString();
  dt = dt.Replace("-", " ");//return 18 Aug 10.
```

But I want the exact format:   `18 Aug 2010`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to always use the English month abbreviation regardless of the thread culture, you should specify the formatting culture as well.  e.g.:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

or

```
.ToString("d MMM yyyy");
```

Depending on if you want the day part as for example "08 Aug" or "8 Aug"

Comment: brilliant downvoting again. I really don't know why I bother with this site.

Comment: It would help your cause if you explain your answer... maybe explain what your is different then the others.... aka dd ..

Comment: @Nix: I don't have to explain anything. My answer is correct, and at the time of posting it was the only correct answer here. If you want to downvote me because a bunch of other people have since added/edited their answers, then whatever.

Comment: You have since updated your answer.  You just had ToString( ) ..  since my comments and your rework you now have 2 votes...thank me later.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d MMM yyyy");
```

[This link](http://dotnetperls.com/datetime-format) has more information on formatting DateTime in C#

Answer (score 1):

```
string formattedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Reference: [Custom DateTime Format Strings (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("d MMM yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Comment: The posts where within seconds of each other? To me this seems like a negative comment that would stifle answers.